# El Circo de Desconcertante

Tags: mathematics, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

Well. It took you long enough. But finally you have tracked El Circo de Desconcertante down to this door in this dismal alley.

[image]

You knew you wouldn't just be allowed in, so you've come prepared with the [information you need](https://docs.google.com/document/d/102ySYifC6Amv5k8rE2yvUEpaEeygIWAmiyU76pnlfMg/edit?usp=sharing). Now it's just a matter of saying the right thing...

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Chat room for theories](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50532/el-circo-de-desconcertante)

Comment: [tag:imgur-maze]?

Comment: @Mithrandir  not in the slightest

Comment: Just asking. When you click and it's a different image, then I get suspicious... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to the partial answer from @mike-limburg and noting that @Techidiot did almost all the work here...

The cipher:

> LJLD K Y I AT O I X FJ I AW O EA K JO B P O ED K YL B LJLD K CO B W O ASN D HE

Can be deciphered by

> applying the vigenere key 'TRIANGLE' because as @mike-limburg found out, the HEX codes of the colours are ASCII for 'LOOK AT THE SHAPES'

Once decoded:

> SSDD X S X WA X A X SD X WD X WA X DD X W X WD X SA X SSDD X WD X D X SSA X WA

That step will be important in a bit.

Next you'll need the image from clicking on the picture of the letter  with the 16 circles as well as the letter text itself.  Again the shape is key here:

> You'll need to extract all the "triangular number" letters from the text:
>   Letters:  1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91 which come from 
>   1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, 1+2+3+4+5, etc.
>   Those letters from the letter fill the 16 circle grid row by row: 
>  TMIS 
>  QXGE 
>  DOUL 
>  HAJN
>
> [image]

Now you need to come back to the decoded cipher:

> Starting with the X on the 4x4 grid of letters, use WASD as keyboard arrows (UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT) to select letters, going back to X when the cipher says X.

The output reads:

> NOT QUITE MIDNIGHT

Which is the rhyme we need to get in.

Comment: What kind of cipher was it?

Comment: @LeppyR64 vigenere

Answer (score 5):

(very) Partial Answer:

By clicking on the first link, we see a picture with different colored stripes. Using a color picker, I discovered the following hex codes for each color:

> 076079 
>  079075 
>  032065 
>  084032 
>  084072 
>  069032 
>  083072 
>  065080 
>  069083

We can decode this numbers

> From ASCII into separate letters.

From there on we read the following sentence:

> LOOK AT THE SHAPES

As @TechIdiot and @Jim found out, the (triangled) shapes say:

> Knock on our door sometime / To enter just say the rhyme

Comment: Good start. The numbers are actually ASCII encoded. You might want to add that.

Comment: "Knock on OUR door sometime" "To enter just say the rhyme"